# Flutter Animated Container as a sidebar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

asking for advice on what I need to search for?
I need something like side navigation but when I open the container it can not overlay the header and button navigations. Chek picture example. Thanks.
So far I understand that Drawer will not help..
[image]

Comment: You can not use drawer because it will show an overlay on the appbar?

Comment: If this is the main reason, then you can use two scaffold nested, in the inner one you can use the drawer also, don't use appbar in the inner one, in that you can achieve what you want to. Remember, it's all about widgets. So you can use as many scaffolds as you need in a single screen.

Comment: `drawer: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight),
child: Drawer(
child: Icon(Icons.add),
),
),`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Your help a lot to understand my problem and solve it!